# NSKeyedArchiver and Apple uploads

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, appstore-approval, nskeyedarchiver

1. What does `NSKeyedArchiver` do to the information I give it? Is it **serialized?**, **encrypted?**, **both?**, **other?** My knowledge both of what constitutes encryption and the actual process of encrypting information is not something I've covered before.
2. If it is counted as encryption, when uploading an application to iTunes Connect, I am asked whether or not my application contains any encryption, I assume the correct answer here would be *yes*. Do I assume correctly? I've avoided using this class in the past lest my app is rejected.

I'm only looking to serialize the information I store in NSUserDefaults to help combat users' 'cheating' by changing the values, (for those of you that don't know how, it can be done, both with and without jailbreaking). I realise the information I store using `NSKeyedArchiver` isn't hack-proof, but I feel making it unreadable at first glance would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver` is serialization.

Also, IIRC the encryption question on iTC doesn't apply if you're only using stuff that comes with the OS. (I.e., you only need to answer "yes" if you're bundling a third-party encryption library. Someone correct me if I'm wrong on this, though.)